# Setting up Spring MVC for restful endpoints, for both json and xml

Tags: xml, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So I got json working where someone can post an object in json form, and my controller method maps that to the actual java object.  My spring config xml looks like:

```
 <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list id="beanList">
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And a test controller method that works is like:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        return user.getName();
    }
```

Now if I want the exact same method to work with xml also, is this possible?
Which message converter do I use?

BTW, if I want to keep certain properties of private, how can I do that so it works for both json and xml?

e.g. say I have a password property, I don't want anyone being able to post this information.

Comment: Make habit to upvote/accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring 3.1 and this is how I'm doing.
In dispatcher-servelet.xml

```
   <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.parth.web.CustomJacksonMapper"/>
    <bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
        <props>
            <prop key="event">com.parth.model.Event</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.parth.model.Event</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxb2Marshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.parth.model.Event"/>
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter" p:marshaller-ref="xstreamMarshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="xstreamMarshaller"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And in Controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Event> getAllEvents(@RequestParam("userId")  String userId, HttpServletResponse response){
        return  eventService.getAll(userId);
    }
```

Now, when you make HTTP request from client make sure you set `Accept` header either with `appliction/json or application/xml`.

As far as omitting fields, you cans use annotations `@JsonIgnore`(for Jackson) and/or `@XStreamOmitField`(for XStream).

Make sure you have Jackson and XStream jars in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any implementation in the [org.springframework.http.converter.xml](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/package-summary.html) package as long as you consider the respective requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the a method what types it will consume through the consumes attribute of the RequestMapping annotation.

I.E. from the Spring Documentation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
```

Note: this is a comma-separated list, so you can also have application/xml as well.

Important to note as well, this will only accept those content-types, which gives you a
bit of safety, but might lead to unexpected results.  What I mean is, if you send `/pets` text/plain, the method will not be called.

To do the correct binding, inspect the content type sent through the `HttpServletRequest` and unmarshal depending on what type you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering this even though its very old in case someone comes across this in a site search) -
You can use ContentNegotiationViewResolver http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one to handle both:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", 
method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers ={"Accept=application/json,application/xml"},
produces={"application/json", "application/xml"})
```