# @Responsebody Spring 3- how to configure which MessageConverter to pick.?

Tags: spring-mvc

Can any one help me how AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter can be configured to pick different MessageConverter to write to responsebody based on value of Accept Header from client.

Explanation of working of responsebody annotation would greatly help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078331/setting-up-spring-mvc-for-restful-endpoints-for-both-json-and-xml/14102873#14102873 this might help you